# Slight difference pre and post boil gravity

Tags: all-grain, boil, off-flavor

Long story short. Trying to understand my new set up, I made a mistake, I didn't check the post boil volume and also didn't have good rolling boil. The wort was boiling, but not so much. Simple grain bill:

- 5.2 kg 2 row (95%),
- 20g Munich (5%)
- first wort hops and 80g more at flameout.

Mashed for 80 minutes at 65°C/149°F, mashed out for 10 minutes at 167°F. Boiled for 60 minutes stirring all the time. Pre-boil gravity was 1.050, after boil 1.056.

What is the chance for off flavors?

Have you had similar experience?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7):

Q1) No chance of off flavors just from this.

Q2) Yes, this is normal. The post boil gravity will always be higher than pre boil because of the water lost to evaporation.

In your case about 12% of the water was boiled off, resulting in a 12% increase in gravity.

Assuming a 5 gallon batch, you boiled off about 0.6 gallons.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.I just was worried about it not high enough usually I had about 2 liters boil of before, was thinking I could get that corny flavor from not strong boil.